# Parsing html br tags with bs4

Tags: beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to parse html pages with lots of parallel < br/> tags
such as

```
<td>
  "a"
  <br>
  "b"
  <br>
  "c"
</td>
```

I want to store these data seperately like
a = ["a"], b=["b"], c=["c"], without any tags attached.

What would be the best way for this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want the same name for the key and value for your result dict.
Anyway, if you want just to have the data between the `<br>` tag and store it you can do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# coding: utf8

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """<td>
  "a"
  <br>
  "b"
  <br>
  "c"
</td>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
td = soup.find('td')
result = []
for val in td.get_text().replace(' ','').split('\n'):
    if val:
        result.append(val)
```

And then `print(result)` will give you the list of data `['"a"', '"b"', '"c"']`